# parse nested json data in loop

Tags: python, json

I would like to parse a json file (data string) with the following structure:

```
{
  "items1": {
     "item1": "value1",
     "item2": "value2"
  },
  "items2": {
     "item" :"value12"
  }, 
  "items3": "null"
}
```

My simple json parser should get the path (e.g. ["items1", "item1"]) to the desired value as input and return the value for the key.

```
# call get_json_value(["items1", "item1"]) should return value1

def get_json_value(path)
  #get json data
  json_data = json.load(get_data())

  # search for specific value in json struct
  value = None #return value with the json value if available 
  tmp = json_data
  for item in path:
   tmp = tmp[item]
   value = tmp

  return value
```

At the moment my script is not working as expected because the leaf of my search is not a key its a value. Therefore the last round in the for loop is raising an exception. How can I solve this? My approach is probably not the right one...

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the same issue when I run your code. Do you think you could post the full error?

Comment: Are you facing this issue for an invalid path / case where an item does not exist?

Comment: As a side issue, what is the purpose of `value`?  You could just use `tmp`.

Comment: The code in your question works for me (after I added missing pieces). Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that shows the problem.

Comment: I had an error in my json string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
import json

def get_json_value(path):
    value = json.load(get_data())
    for item in path:
        value = value[item]
    return value
```

or this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def get_json_value(path):
    return reduce(getitem, path, json.load(get_data()))
```

Assume that your problem is that you give invalid path as argument to function. In this case, the question is, should your code catch such exceptions? If so, you can write something like:

```
def get_json_value(path):
    value = json.load(get_data())
    for item in path:
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            try:
                value = value[item]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                continue
        raise ValueError(f'invalid path {item!r}')
    return value
```